# Apex Input field Not passing any values to controller

Tags: apex, visualforce

My visual force code is:
The object variable is of the type list and it contains a list of my subclass objects.

```
 <apex:inputText id="test" value="{!object.value}" rendered="{!contains(object.type, 'String')}" >
 </apex:inputText>
```

Controller:

```
 Public Class SubClass{
     public string value {get; set;}

}
```

The object is a sub-class in my controller and the value is a field of my sub-class object. The inputText seems to to be not passing the value to the appropriate field. Why is this happening? Please help! Thank you.

Comment: How is this page being submitted to the controller? Can we see a little more of your code?

Answer (score 1):

Try use instance of subclass as varible in your controller

```
public SubClass object {get; set;}
```

And subclass as

```
Public Class SubClass{
     public string value;

}
```

Comment: as an aside, 'object' is listed as an Apex reserved word marked for future use per Spring 14 doc - implying it should not be used as an identifier

Comment: good point :) Sorry I just copied @ths code

Comment: I think in the OP, they are iterating over a list of SubClass objects (using `var="object"` in the VF tag), rather than one individual instance.